# Remove table rows containing empty cell

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to remove rows from table that contains an empty cell using javascript, this table is loaded in a partial view (modal view). I tried a few javascript codes, but since i am a new at javascript i am unable to understand why those code aren't doing the task. This is one of the codes i used:

```
    @model managemnet.Models.Department

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_DetailDepartmentPartialView";
}
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="@("DetailDepartment-"+Model.DepId)" aria-labelledby="DetailDepartmentLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Department</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <dl class="row">
                                              
                         ..........

                        <dt class="col-sm-3">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employees)

                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-10">


                        </dd>

                    </dl>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-12 ">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    
                                    <th>Employee name</th>
                                    <th>Profession</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i++)
                                {
                                <tr>
                                    
                                    <td>
                                        <input asp-for="@Model.Employees[i].EmpName" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input asp-for="@Model.Employees[i].Profession" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input asp-for="@Model.Employees[i].Phone" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>                    
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>        
    $(function () {
        const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
        const emptyCells = Array.from(cells).filter(cell => cell.innerHTML === '');
        emptyCells.forEach(cell => cell.parentNode.remove());
    });        
</script>
```

This script is not removing the rows with empty cell, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set a name for the table to be able reference to:

```js
<table class="table" id="myTable">
```

Then use:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {             
            var empty = true;
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                if (col.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value != '') {
                    empty = false;
                    break;
                }                    
            }
            if (empty) {
                row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```